# OsmBonuspack - GeocoderNominatim::getFromLocationName - Invalid response from server: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: android, geocoding, osmdroid

My GeocoderNominatim.getFromLocation() was working just fine.

Now I get an error during GeocoderNominatim without changing anything!?

**Invalid response from server: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden**

My Logcat-Output:

```
02-02 11:15:31.570: D/BONUSPACK(25238): GeocoderNominatim::getFromLocationName:http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&accept-language=de&addressdetails=1&limit=1&q=Bolivia
02-02 11:15:32.210: E/BONUSPACK(25238): Invalid response from server: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

The check in the Browser works fine ( http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&accept-language=de&addressdetails=1&limit=1&q=Bolivia )

My AsyncTask:

```
 public class SearchGeocode extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<Address>> {

    Context context = MainActivity.this;
    GeocoderNominatim coderNominatim = new GeocoderNominatim(context);
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String countryTitleString;

    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... countryTitle) {

        int i = 0;
        publishProgress(i);

        countryTitleString = Arrays.toString(countryTitle);

        List<Address> geoResults = null;
        try {
            geoResults = coderNominatim.getFromLocationName(countryTitleString, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Geocoding error! Internet available?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return geoResults;

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> geoResults) {
        super.onPostExecute(geoResults);

         progressDialog.hide();

        if (geoResults.size() == 0) { //if no address found, display an error
            Toast.makeText(context, countryTitleString +" - Country not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Address address = geoResults.get(0);
            Bundle extras = address.getExtras();
            BoundingBoxE6 bb = extras.getParcelable("boundingbox");
            mapView.zoomToBoundingBox(bb);
            //makeToast(countryTitle);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why I get an invalid response from the Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: in june 2015, Nominatim changed their usage policy, and now require a user agent.

So GeocoderNominatim constructor [evolved](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/issues/284), and requires you to set your user agent. Typically, something like: "your_application/version"

You can also look at GeocoderNominatim javadoc.

(I guess you are using a pretty old version of OSMBonusPack)

Comment: Thanks! I was using a old version of OSMDroid & OSMBonuspack.

`final String userAgent = "[App_Name]/[App_Version]";`
`GeocoderNominatim coderNominatim = new GeocoderNominatim(context, userAgent);`